# Camera crashes when Flutter App opened on Chrome on Mac

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have implemented code which will allow me to access the camera in my flutter application and it is working perfectly when the app is opened on android, but the app crashes and throws an exception when I open the same, on Chrome on Mac!

I am using camera package from flutter docs to access the camera!

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
```

The exception occurs at this line:

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
```

I don't know whether camera package supports on web or not, so if this is the case, can anyone suggest me an alternative, which I can use in web and a way how to write a condition, like if the app opened on web then the alternative camerapreview, else (on android) camerapreview from camera package

Edit - when I accept the permission of camera on chrome, the light of the webcam blinks and then the app crashes and points to the above line showcasing exception occurs

Comment: Which exception?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user18309290 edited the question with the exception